# rkhunter /usr/bin/ssh && /usr/sbin/sshd [Warning]

Tags: debian, ssh, process, sshd, chkrootkit

My last rkhunter scan reported a couple of warnings that deserve to be checked. Main reason for my suspect is that I wasn't on the machine at (03-Apr-2014 01:12:12) ->AM

I googled for understand what's the purpose of the 2 files I mentioned in question title, but I didn't find very helpful answers. Can anybody tell me what's the aim of those files, and maybe also why/when it would be modified by the system itself?

```
[10:17:11] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[10:17:11]          File: /usr/sbin/sshd
[10:17:11]          Current hash: 900e153506754ceb7b19f3a01a3ad5e36d43d958
[10:17:11]          Stored hash : 55a1a63a46d84eb9d0322f96bd9a61f070e90698
[10:17:11]          Current inode: 149998    Stored inode: 142248
[10:17:11]          Current file modification time: 1396480332 (03-Apr-2014 01:12:12)
[10:17:11]          Stored file modification time : 1360359087 (08-Feb-2013 22:31:27)
```

---

```
[10:17:34] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[10:17:34]          File: /usr/bin/ssh
[10:17:34]          Current hash: 60366d414c711a70f9e313f5ff26213ca513b565
[10:17:34]          Stored hash : 1b410fb0de841737f963e1ee011989f155f41259
[10:17:34]          Current inode: 150030    Stored inode: 142203
[10:17:34]          Current file modification time: 1396480332 (03-Apr-2014 01:12:12)
[10:17:34]          Stored file modification time : 1360359087 (08-Feb-2013 22:31:27)
```

the apt logs files making me worry, I censored couple of info. Apparently in the 03-Apr-2014 I didn't installed nothing.

```
Start-Date: 2014-04-01  15:49:18
Commandline:  ***********
Install:  ***********
End-Date: 2014-04-01  15:49:29

Start-Date: 2014-04-08  14:03:52
Commandline:  ***********
Install:  ***********
End-Date: 2014-04-08  14:04:04
```

By the way I think (hope) they are false positives [edit:not anymore]. Maybe files edited by some process of the system and normally not recorded in the .dat file of rkhunter because I didn't updated. I came here to find some confirmation or some more paranoia.

Comment: What does your apt log say about upgrades around that time? Do you automatically install security upgrades?

Comment: Thankyou for your hint. No i still don't use automatic updates. i edited the question for apt log files - im getting worry é,è

Comment: If the ssh and sshd binaries changed by themselves, and you are sure you didn't do it, that seems very suspicious. What kind of server is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hash of the program should NOT change if you did not update your SSH. Also, it shows you the time when the file was modified (03-Apr-2014), so if you did not update `openssh` packages, it is not a false positive.

Comment: do you think that uninstall openssh purging configuration files, and reinstalling it, could help in anyway to fix what is been made?

Comment: Configuration files will have nothing to do with this. It's only 2 binary files that got changed, so only reinstalling the old version of the package will do. Modification date/time will be when the package was packaged, not installed.

Comment: ok thanks, and when the process of packaging the package usually happens? i guess right after an upgrade or a fresh install, but not hours later, right?

Comment: when "packaging" I mean when Debian packages it before releasing to repositories. But I am not sure on that, you need to test it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Google brouth me here. I guess I was also hacked. Same message from rkhunter.
Here are some ways to analyze a little further.

To be sure, you can check the md5sum with

```
sudo cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/openssh-client.md5sums
md5sum /usr/bin/ssh
```

Another way is

```
dpkg --verify openssh-server
```

empty is ok, you have problems if you see ??5??????   /usr/sbin/sshd

You can also install debsums which makes it easier to check

```
sudo apt-get install debsums
sudo debsums | grep -v OK
```

This was my list. I think it's still using local sums. 
Would be more secure if it can be done with an official debian mirror.
Does somebody know how to do this?

```
debsums: missing file /usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h (from libssl-dev:amd64 package)
debsums: missing file /usr/include/openssl/x509v3.h (from libssl-dev:amd64 package)
/usr/bin/scp                                                              FAILED
/usr/bin/sftp                                                             FAILED
/usr/bin/ssh                                                              FAILED
/usr/bin/ssh-add                                                          FAILED
/usr/bin/ssh-agent                                                        FAILED
/usr/bin/ssh-keygen                                                       FAILED
/usr/bin/ssh-keyscan                                                      FAILED
/usr/sbin/sshd                                                            FAILED
/usr/bin/rkhunter                                                         FAILED
```